# Programming idiom for "increment number up to a value"

Tags: idioms

Often I come across a situation where I need to "loop" a number. That is to say that given a value X, I need to increment it up to a point and then loop back to zero. This usually results in some fairly verbose code with a lot of "plus 1"s. Is there a nice one-liner or some other nice idiom to do this?

Example (JS carousel used for ease):

```
function cycle() {

    const $e = $('.a-carousel');
    const activeClass = 'active';

    var activeIndex = $e.find('.' + activeClass).removeClass(activeClass).index();
    if (activeIndex + 1 >= $e.children().length) {
        activeIndex = -1;
    }

    $e.children().eq(activeIndex + 1).addClass(activeClass);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the cyclic *successor* of a value *k*<sub>*i*</sub> in range *k*<sub>0</sub>, ..., *k*<sub>*n*-1</sub> is defined as

next( *k*<sub>*i*</sub> ) = (*k*<sub>*i*</sub> - *k*<sub>0</sub> + 1) mod *n* + *k*<sub>0</sub>

For example,

```
range = 3 ... 9
k0 = 3
n = 7

k    k-k0    k-k0+1    k-k0+1 mod n    k-k0+1 mod n + k0
------------------------------------------------------------
6     3        4           4            7
7     4        5           5            8
8     5        6           6            9
9     6        7           0            3
3     0        1           1            4
4     1        2           2            5
5     2        3           3            6
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a special term for this, but your code is more verbose than it needs to be.  You can do it with one increment, and one `if` check.

(in pseudo-code)

```
x = MinValue
Loop
    Increment x
    If x > MaxValue
        x = MinValue
    Do things with x
```